# What is the use of Perform Selector in objective C/Iphone development

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, performselector

What is the use of perform selector in objective C? and can you please tell  me the difference between perform selector and responds selector?

Answer (score 5):

**-respondsToSelector:** allows you to test if a certain object responds to a given selector, of if your app would crash if you still sent the message to it.

---

**-performSelector:(withObject:)** simply invokes a certain method, e.g.

```
[object performSelector:@selector(retain)];
```

would be equal to

```
[object retain];
```

---

Why do you need that?
A handy example is provided by `NSArray`: it allows a selector to be performed by all objects it contains, e.g.

```
[self.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

would be equal to

```
for (UIView *view in self.subviews)
{
    [view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

whereas the `-makeObjectsPerformSelector:` is way more elegant.

Comment: Thank you Jenox and Nit.Thank you for your support.And if it is convinient could you please tell me how multi threading is managed in objecitive c and is there any relationship between perform selector and multithreading?

Answer (score 0):

**respondsToSelector:** Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether the receiver implements or inherits a method that can respond to a specified message.

**performSelector:** Sends a specified message to the receiver and returns the result of the message.

PerformSelector  is used to call method as you want perform that means that you have option to select different option for performing particular task(Method) Example...

– performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: // will execute method after specific delay..
– performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:inModes:
– performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:
– performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:modes:
– performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:
– performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:modes:

– performSelectorInBackground:withObject:  // Perform task in background. So, Your ManinThread(Application) will not stop responding..like multithreading..

Where direct method will not provide selection for performing task..

[For more and detailed explanation visit this reference..](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Hope,this will help you...

Comment: As of my Knowledge PerformSelector is used for enhancing multi threading or something.is it correct or what is the relevance of calling a function through perform selector instead of calling it directly?

Comment: Thank you for the valid answer and can you please excuse one mor doubt please?I have heard that – performSelectorInBackground:withObject: can be used for fetching data from the database without hanging the app.Is that correct?

Comment: He wants to know what it is used for, not what methods there are...  Check my answer, @harikrishnan.

Comment: @Jenox : I think..I have covered all the thing including meaning and fundamentals and usage as well..

Answer (score 0):

A typical usage of performSelector is to send message to an object when you don't know whether it is valid to do so.

For example, assuming you have a `@property (assign) id delegate` in your interface, where `id` is a pointer to any kind of object. Even if the `delegate` is not `nil`, you don't know whether it implements the proper protocol you created for the delegate when compiling your code. So you can:

```
if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(delegateMethod:)]) {
    [delegate performSelector:@selector(delegateMethod:)
                   withObject:param];
}
```

This can also be used when you need to detect the type of an object. You can use `performSelector:` to avoid type casting. Also this eliminates unnecessary warnings at compile time.

For multi-thread scenarios, you may want to use these methods of `NSObject`:

```
performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:
performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:modes:
performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:
performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:modes:
performSelectorInBackground:withObject:
```

Reference:

- https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html
- https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html